# extract multiple expressions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell that contains usernames assigned to projects like this

`,FC757_random_name,AP372_another_one,FC782_again_different,FC082_samesamebutdifferent,`

I need to only extract the alphanumeric values the expressions start with, so everything in between `,` and `_`.

I made it work for one expression with the following, but I need all of them.

`= MID(A1;FIND(",";A1)+1;FIND("_";A1)-FIND(",";A1)-1)`

I also tinkered with Text to Data, but couldn't make it work for multiple lines at once.
Ideally this would work only with formulas, but I guess (/fear) I'll need VBA or Macros, which I have never worked with before.

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you planning to put 'all of them'?

Comment: is there always a starting comma?

Comment: `Text To Columns` will split the values out using the comma and underscore as delimiters in the Wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) based User Defined Function.

```
Option Explicit

Function extractMultipleExpressions(str As String, _
                  Optional delim As String = ", ")
    Dim n As Long, nums() As Variant
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    extractMultipleExpressions = vbNullString

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            'resize the nums array to accept the matches
            ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
            'populate the nums array with the matches
            For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                nums(n) = cmat.Item(n)
            Next n
            'convert the nums array to a delimited string
            extractMultipleExpressions = Join(nums, delim)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this Press `Alt + F11` and then choose *Insert > Module* and then paste the following code:

```
Public Function GetUsers(UserNameProject As String)

Dim userArray() As String
Dim users As String
Dim intPos As Integer

'this will split the users into an array based on the commas
userArray = Split(UserNameProject, ",")

'loop through the array and process any non blank element and extract user
'based on the position of the first underscore
For i = LBound(userArray) To UBound(userArray)
      If Len(Trim(userArray(i))) > 0 Then
        intPos = InStr(1, userArray(i), "_")
        users = users & "," & Left(userArray(i), intPos - 1)
      End If
Next

GetUsers = users

End Function
```

If your string is in A1 then use by putting `=GetUsers(A1)` in the approiate cell. I think this should get you started!

Answer (score 0):

To clean the data of extra commas, use this formula in cell B1:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";"||");";";" "));" ";";");"||";" "))
```

Then use this formula in cell C1 and copy over and down to extract just the part you want from each section:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($B1;";";REPT(" ";LEN($B1)));LEN($B1)*(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A;LEN($B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B1;";";""))+1))-1)+1;LEN($B1)));"_";REPT(" ";LEN($B1)));LEN($B1)));COLUMN(A1));"")
```